# Why is the math in Winnie the Pooh's so poor? Is it deliberate?

Tags: literature, books

Earlier, I was reading *Winnie the Pooh* by A. A. Milne and lit upon this passage:

> Piglet is so small that he slips into a pocket, where it is very
>   comforting to feel him when you are not quite sure whether twice seven
>   is twelve or twenty-two.

I was confused because twice seven should be 14, not 12 nor 22.

What's the idea?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question is why the author uses wrong numbers.

Comment: I'm not sure it's really a good question for this site - maybe Literature would be better, but keep in mind that the characters in Winnie the Pooh are stuffed animals and stuffed animals are carried around by very small children who are bad at math.

Comment: Why is this tagged "american-english"?

Comment: Azor Ahal "very small children who are bad at math" - and even worse at arithmetic.

Comment: You might want to check out the [site tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) to figure out what is and what isn't considered on-topic for this site, as well as [how to ask a good question](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: The author is trying to create a sense of a small child who is unsure about the world around him/her as it is new and big and confusing.  He is doing so by explicitly mentioning the confusion between 12 and 22 as well as distancing the child from the reader who surely knows that the correct answer is 14.  It makes it even clearer to the reader that the emotion is one of complete lack of knowledge, rather than getting mixed up between the right answer and a wrong one.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about English; it is about understanding.

Comment: It's similar to the difference in feelings when you're not sure of the spelling of a word you know how to spell (is it _friend_ or _freind_?) and when you have no clue how to spell something (how _do_ you spell _ehpitohmy_?).

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I don't know what the difference is in this context

Comment: @Kimia I think the sentence is demonstrating, in an explicit way, that Piglet is a comfort when you're feeling confused. Just as you were by the seemingly strange math. :) (It's a kind of "meta" statement.)